# Python pandas multiplying 2 columns results in incorrect product

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
vwapDataGMD.head()
Out[311]:
                         price  size    return      logP         priceVol
time
2013-01-02 08:00:03  29.280000   800       NaN  3.376905  78863044.800000
2013-01-02 08:00:05  29.308889   900  0.000986  3.377891  78940854.422222
2013-01-02 08:15:29  29.314348   230  0.000186  3.378077  78955557.578261
2013-01-02 08:24:21  29.400000   158  0.002918  3.380995  79186254.000000
2013-01-02 08:35:48  29.400000   100  0.000000  3.380995  79186254.000000
```

When I multiply the price and size columns, I get the priceVol column which is incorrect. For e.g. 29.28 * 800 = priceVol = 23424 but I am getting a high number in priceVol = 78863044.800

My code was the following:

```
vwapDataGMD['priceVol'] = vwapDataGMD.price * vwapDataGMD.size
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's because you use `vwapDataGMD.size` to access the column. But pandas think it as the keyword `size` and hence returns the length of dataframe. use this instead `vwapDataGMD['priceVol'] = vwapDataGMD['price'] * vwapDataGMD['size']`

Comment: @JianxunLi: nice deduction!

Comment: @JianxunLi: Please post it as an answer, so it can be voted up and (hopefully) accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you use `vwapDataGMD.size` to access the column. But pandas think it as the keyword `size` and hence returns the length of dataframe. Use the following instead.

```
vwapDataGMD['priceVol'] = vwapDataGMD['price'] * vwapDataGMD['size']
```